# when adding row with jquery datatables - it's adding a row multiple times. Not just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to send data through ajax to my DB, on success it shows a notification and adds a row to a datatable with the note / info the user just posted.

For some reason it's adding the row twice, instead of just once. Cant figure out why.

My code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#notestable').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "filter": false
        });    

    $("#addnote").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var note = $("#note1").val();
      var leadid = "<?echo $lead->leadid;?>";
      $.ajax({
        url: "/leads/addnote",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          note: note,
          leadid: leadid
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#closemodal12').trigger('click');
          swal({
            title: "Note added",
            type: "success",
          });

          var notestable1 = $('#notestable').DataTable();

          var lengthToCut = 23;
          var short = note.substr(0, lengthToCut);
          var i = 1;
          var row = $('<tr>');
          row.append('<td>' + short + ' </td>')
            .append('<td><? echo $user->forename;?></td>')
            .append('<td><? echo date('d / m / Y ');?> </td>')
            .append('<td><? echo date('H: i ');?> </td>')
            .append('<td><i class ="fa fa-eye"> </i></td>')
            .append('<td><i class ="fa fa-trash-o"> </i></td>')
          notestable1.row.add(row);
          $('#notestable tbody').prepend(row);



        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Slight problem");
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the markup that goes along with this, it's difficult to be sure, but I believe the problem lies with these two lines of code:

```
// Append row to notestable1 (already visible in DOM)
notestable1.row.add(row);

// (pre)Append the row again
$('#notestable tbody').prepend(row);
```

`notestable1` appears to be a valid object, already inserted into the DOM, that you're appending the row to. You then append the row again using `$('#notestable tbody').prepend(row)`.